# Selenium Subselect waiting in java

Tags: java, unit-testing, selenium, testing

I have 3 select menus depending on each other. Selenium enables you to select a value of a select item but since the menus depend on each other there is a small waiting time between each one. You can have a thread sleeping for one second the time it loads  but I want to know how to make the waiting dynamic. The WebDriverWait enables you to wait for an element but not a value of the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The secret to dynamic waits is the [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) class. Used properly, you can get WebDriverWait to work with quite a large variety of conditions.

Without seeing the HTML of your page, I suspect you're going to need something like:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions
    .textToBePresentInElementLocated(By.id("the-element's-id", "Value you are looking for");
```

You don't have to use id if it's not convenient: any of the usual locators like xpath and css will work too.